# How to express set difference in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Just for the sake of asking the question, let's say I have a type nullableId declared as below:

```
type nullableId = number | string | null
```

and then suddenly I need to have a nonNullableId type that is pretty much like nullableId:

```
type nonNullableId = number | string
```

For me, the ideal way (that does not exist) to do this is something like this:

```
type idealExpressionOfNonNullableId = nullableId ∆ null
```

How do I express the `∆` in the line below using typescript?

P.S. I am aware of the utility type `NonNullable`, but let's focus on the set difference part.

Comment: Do you mean symmetric difference to be more precise?

Answer (score 4):

## General pattern

Using *conditional types* you can omit types from a set. This is exactly what the `NonNullable` does:

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T;
```

Map what you what to remove to `never` and keep the rest.

## Built in type

The built in type `Exclude` does that for you e.g. instead of using `NonNullable` (which removes both null and undefined) you can write the type that just removes `null`:

```
type NullableId = number | string | null;
type NonNullId = Exclude<NullableId, null>;
```

Here is the type definition for `Exclude`:

```
type Exclude<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

Comment: Fine answer, but note that the OP asked for how to express type difference. That is the Diff<> operator.

Comment: Thanks. We are talking about the same operator. Its called `Exclude` though.